# Highcharts pointer cursor for chart click event

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I have a Highcharts solid gauge chart. [Here is an example on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/guidoman/aL2tstoy/).

I want to configure a click event when the user clicks on any part of the chart, not just on the data. I can do that in the following way:

```
chart: {
            type: 'solidgauge',
            events:{
                click: function(event) {
                    alert('Chart clicked but no pointer cursor...');
                }
            }
        }
```

I also want a cursor pointer to be displayed when the mouse is over the chart. Highcharts usually provides a `cursor` option, but not in the case of `chart`. I have tried to put `cursor: "pointer"` anywhere, but nothing worked.

Note that in the same example I have configured a click event for `series` and it works as expected (i.e. when hovering the mouse over the green area the pointer cursor is displayed).

Comment: What about putting `cursor: pointer` in the style attribute of the `container-speed` div?

Answer (score 1):

Highcharts lets you set chart's class so use a css class:

```
 chart: {
    className: 'pointChart',
    type: 'solidgauge', ........
```

and

```
.pointChart
{
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aL2tstoy/3/

Comment: I had already tried something similar, but it doesn't satisfy me 100%. Look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/guidoman/uehns1uu/): the **chart title** is not clickable. It's confusing for the user...

Comment: Have you tried `$('.highcharts-title').on("click", function(){
    alert('chart clicked');
});` if you want alert on title click that is.
`

Comment: OK thanks, it works. CSS and jQuery together do the trick and solve my problem. Anyway the purpose of my question was to look for a "native" Highcharts solution...